# Como criar uma Thread em Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, thread, multiple-file-upload

Estou iniciando uma aplicação de file upload de arquivos, onde grava o caminho no banco e a imagem no servidor, ao realizar um teste conseguir enviar a imagem para a pasta, agora preciso conseguir criar o local temporário quando quando for submeter o formulário com outras propriedades  a imagem possa ser submetida no mesmo momento, mas para isso acontecer é necessário esse local temporário com Thread.

Conseguir o modelo de simples upload através [desse repositório](https://github.com/algaworks/videoaula-spring-api-rest-upload/tree/master/contato-api) , essa aplicação só está enviando o arquivo para pasta, mas a principio só preciso disso no momento.

Minha aplicação atualmente está assim;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FotosResource {

//  @PostMapping
//  public void upload(@RequestParam MultipartFile files) {
//      disco.salvarFoto(files);
//  }   

    @PostMapping
    public DeferredResult<String> upload(@RequestParam MultipartFile files) {
        DeferredResult<String> resultado = new DeferredResult<>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new FotoStorageRunnable(files, resultado));
        thread.start();



        return resultado;
    }


}
```

E tentei criar essa Thread;

```
public class FotoStorageRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private Disco disco;

    private MultipartFile files;
    private DeferredResult<String> resultado;

    public FotoStorageRunnable(MultipartFile files, DeferredResult<String> resultado) {
        this.files = files;
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        disco.salvarFoto(files);
        resultado.setResult("OK! Foto recebida!");

    }

}
```

Ao executar a aplicação no STS gerou esse erro no console, estou usando Spring Boot;

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.algaworks.contato.storage.FotoStorageRunnable.run(FotoStorageRunnable.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Está indicando que o erro está nessa linha de código;

> disco.salvarFoto(files);

Como faço para o erro ser corrigido?

O comportamento esperado seria ele funcionar da mesma forma como estava se comportando antes da alteração, conseguindo enviar o arquivo selecionado para pasta.

=============ATUALIZAÇÃO=========

```
@Component
public class Disco {

    @Value("${contato.disco.raiz}")
    private String raiz;

    @Value("${contato.disco.diretorio-fotos}")
    private String diretorioFotos;

    public void salvarFoto(MultipartFile files) {
        this.salvar(this.diretorioFotos, files);
    }

    public void salvar(String diretorio, MultipartFile arquivo) {
        Path diretorioPath = Paths.get(this.raiz, diretorio);
        Path arquivoPath = diretorioPath.resolve(arquivo.getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(diretorioPath);
            arquivo.transferTo(arquivoPath.toFile());           
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problemas na tentativa de salvar arquivo.", e);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: geralmente a classe precisa estar com a anotação prototype ( o padrão é single ) então em tese não tem como rodar uma coisa só em paralelo

Comment: Eu lamento em dizer que você está totalmente equivocado, dar uma olhada nesse repositório https://github.com/algaworks/curso-sistemas-web-com-spring-javascript-bootstrap/blob/master/14.4-melhorando-a-disponibilidade-da-aplicacao-retorno-assincrono/brewer/src/main/java/com/algaworks/brewer/storage/FotoStorageRunnable.java

E veja esse  https://github.com/algaworks/curso-sistemas-web-com-spring-javascript-bootstrap/blob/master/14.4-melhorando-a-disponibilidade-da-aplicacao-retorno-assincrono/brewer/src/main/java/com/algaworks/brewer/controller/FotosController.java

Comment: E esse projeto funciona perfeitamente, só tem uma diferença, esse projeto que te mostrei é em Spring FrameWorks e o meu projeto é feito em Spring Boot.

Comment: " você está totalmente equivocado" : não estou não, mas o possível motivo do seu nullpointer é você não ter anotado seu bean Disco e devido a isso sua dependencia não injeta

Comment: Por favor Lucas Miranda, como eu poderia colocar a anotação na class Disco?

Comment: você poderia anotar a class com por exemplo "@Component"
ex:
"@Component
public class Disco{

}"

Comment: Lucas Miranda, ela já estava com essa anotação. vou atualiza a postagem para você ver, teria mais alguma outra sugestão?